# Failed to execute 'openDatabase' on 'Window': Access to the WebDatabase API is denied in this context

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins

1) I am using my own custom plugin of paytm and got success callback from plugin.

2) After callback it will resume to the app and i got error like **Failed to execute 'openDatabase' on 'Window': Access to the WebDatabase API is denied in this context.**

3)so,I can't go to any page after that. Any suggestion how to over come from that error.

Comment: I am having the same issue. Modifying plugin code and running inside
"this.cordova.getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {..."
DIDN'T help... If you have managed to solve this, please help me